# Why do I get 'Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference'?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I wrote an angular service:

```
app.factory('newService', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    getCustomer: function(id) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('/api/customers?id=' + id).success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve({
          id: 1,
          name: 'Bert'
        });
      }).error(function(err, msg) {
        deferred.reject(msg);
        $log(err);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
});
```

My test looks like this:

```
it('should call service', function() {
    $scope.test2();
    expect(myMock.getCustomer).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
});
```

However I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference
```

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/PHIklcth6uqyYJFcaoLU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `defer` unnecessarily. When you return it, it hasn't resolved yet because that gets set in the http promise. Change your `getCustomer` to

```
getCustomer: function(id) {
  return $http.get('/api/customers?id=' + id).success(function(data) {
    return {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Bert'
    };
  }).error(function(err, msg) {
    $log(err);
    return msg;

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a mock `newService` with a method `getCustomer` but this is just a fake method. It does not have the `then()`function so an error is throw when JS tries to find it in your call to `$scope.test2()`.

You will have to mock this function too.

Also, you should refactor your service as your use of `$q` is redundant since `$http.get()` already returns a promise.

```
app.factory('newService', function($http) {

  return {

    getCustomer: function(id) {

      return $http
        .get('/api/customers?id=' + id)
        .then(function(data){
          return {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Bert'
          };
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          $log(err);
        });
    }

  };

});
```